# ReST or message broker or some other approach for integrating an on-premise and a cloud based spring boot application

Tags: spring-boot, spring-integration, spring-cloud, spring-cloud-stream

I have 2 spring boot applications

- On-premise teller application
- Cloud based multi-tenant application that aggregates data from all teller applications

The teller application has to work offline(if connectivity is down) as well. What is the best approach to broadcast events from the teller application to the cloud. I would not prefer to implement code to persist events.

What is the best approach? ReST/message broker or some other approach. If using a message broker, will the spring cloud stream abstraction queue events when the connection to the broker is down and retry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would go with the message broker (rabbit, kafka) and spring-cloud-stream, since your use case was exactly what/how it was designed.
The microservcice (your app) is a consumer of the broker, that is: *it can publish to and/or consume events from the broker*. If the app is down the broker is up and potentially collecting events destined to the down app. Once app is up it consumes queued up events and so on.
I'll stop here given the general nature of your question but feel free to follow up with more details.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. What happens if the teller app looses connectivity with the cloud. Can the cloud stream abstraction be configured to queue the events and publish all the pending events when the connectivity is back?

Comment: You are now asking about application level concerns at he very high level. The _looses connectivity with the cloud_ can mean a many different things and without knowing the full context I don't think it's an answerable question. Obviously you can make your application do whatever, which includes maintaining some state until something happens (e.g., connectivity to the cloud is restored). But what IF the app that maintains the state fails until connectivity to the cloud is restored? There are many more "what IFs", so consider less general, more pointed question. . .